# about the mean_naive i wrote this code but the error is (shapes (2, 1), (3,) mismatch) so what should i do?

Tags: python, numpy

```py
# GRADED FUNCTION: DO NOT EDIT THIS LINE
def mean_naive(X):
    "Compute the mean for a dataset X nby iterating over the data points"
    # X is of size (D,N) where D is the dimensionality and N the number of data points
    D, N = X.shape
    mean = np.zeros((D,1))
    ### Edit the code; iterate over the dataset and compute the mean vector.
        # Update the mean vector
    for n in range(N):
        # Update the mean vector
        for i in range(D):
            mean[i] += X[i][n]
    mean /= N
    mean = (np.sum(X,axis=1)/N).reshape(D,1)
    
    return mean
```

Comment: People should not need to read your question title.  Please give a super short description in the question title, and state the actual problem in the question body.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code on Python version 3.9.12 I don't get an error.

Code below outputs the same thing as your code:

```py
def mean_naive(X):
    
    # Create an empty list to hold the mean vector - i'm calling it mean
    # For each row in X, find the mean of that row
    # Append to the empty list created at the beginning
    # Reshape mean to be in the shape of a vector
    
    mean = []
    
    for row in X:
        mean.append(np.sum(row)/len(row))
    
    return np.reshape(mean,(len(mean),1))
```

Code below is the same thing as the code above,

```
def mean_naive(X):
    
    # Except this time, we don't need to create an empty list
    # Mean values are automatically appended
    
    mean = [np.sum(row)/len(row) for row in X]
    return np.reshape(mean,(len(mean),1))
```